# Reading a vector from Linux Read

Tags: linux, c++11

I am trying to read the contents of http://linux.die.net/man/2/read
into a vector.  I did this but it doesn't work

```
std::vector<uint32_t> buf(10);
read( m_fileDescriptor, &buf[0], sizeof(buffer[0]));
```

The vector is always zero, if I devmem then it is not zero.  Anyideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use :

```
std::vector<uint32_t> buf(10);
std::size_t n = read (m_fileDescriptor, buf.data(),
             buf.size() * sizeof(*buf.data()));
buf.resize(n / sizeof(*buf.data()));
```

Comment: Almost -- `n` is still in bytes :)